# An adjective for Seneca

Tags: word-request, adjective, names, seneca

A particular passage in Cicero's works is a *locus Ciceronianus*, a work written in the style of Vergil is an *opus Vergilianum* etc.

But which adjective should I use for Seneca?

There exists apparently something called the *Comparativus Senecanus*, a term coined by [Otto Regenbogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Regenbogen), a renowned 20th century philologist. But aside from that, and a few (presumably Renaissance-era) personal names, the word appears not to be used much. In a worrying [Google Books hit](https://books.google.de/books?id=QolMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA496&dq=senecanus%20-comparativus&hl=de&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&ovdme=1&sa=X#v=onepage&q=senecanus%20-comparativus&f=false), [Lucian Müller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucian_M%C3%BCller) disparages Rudolf Peiper's latinity thus:

> By the way, the Latin language does not appear to be Mr. P.'s forte in other ways either. For example, on p. 21, he has the adjective "Senecanus" ...

Why is that so terrible? And if not that, what else? Perhaps *Senecanius*? Or *Senecanianus* or *Senecanensis*? Or is there a whole other way?

Comment: Cf. Catullan v. Catullian; I'm actually not 100% sure why Senecan is *wrong*. I have seen Senecean/Senecaeanus before, but on the other hand, we have the infamous *Sullani* attested in Cicero, so perhaps it has to do with the root?

Comment: I think that *Senecānus* is good. Cf. *Āfrica*, *āfricānus* (used e.g. in name of Pūblius Cornēlius Scīpiō Āfricānus).

Comment: @Arfrever, Wiktionary (not sure what the source) does distinguish between [-ianus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ianus#Latin), and [-anus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-anus#Latin). The former is said to be "especially frequent in adjectives formed from proper names."; while the later "usually indicates a relationship of position, possession, or origin.". So there is perhaps basis for *africanus* as opposed to *Senecanus*. (though it seems Wiktionary -anus encapsulates also --ianus); If there is a person name the same as a place we could put the theory into test.

Comment: @d_e But that wouldn't explain *Sullanus*.

Comment: *-iānus* is probably result of [rebracketing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#rebracketing) of adjectives with *-ānus* following stems ending in *-i*, *-io*, *-ia* etc. (e.g. *Marius* +‎ *-ānus* → *Mariānus*). Compare etymology of suffix [*-ellus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ellus#Latin).